# Getting 'invalid argument for foreach' for a valid array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm getting the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` even though the array being supplied appears to be a valid array. Here's my code:

```
print_r($keywords);
extract($product);
foreach ($keywords as $k=>$v)
{
   //stuff here
}
```

Here's some of the output from the print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => vanguard tripod
            [language] => 
            [advertiserCompetitionScale] => 0
            [avgSearchVolume] => -1
            [lastMonthSearchVolume] => -1
        )
    .........
    [39] => Array
        (
            [text] => 63 for sale
            [language] => 
            [advertiserCompetitionScale] => 0
            [avgSearchVolume] => 6600
            [lastMonthSearchVolume] => -1
        )

)
```

The error I get is on the line where I do the foreach.

The array `$keywords` is retrieved by doing an `array_merge` on two similar arrays. Could that have anything to do this this?

Comment: In case it isn't clear, i've snipped the print_r from element 0 to element 39, the .... you see is added by me, it isn't there in the actual output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `$products` contain an element named `keywords`?

If so, `print_r` after the `extract`.  `extract` is likely the issue here.